# Putting variables in Python

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm a complete newbie to Python (and programming itself for that matter) and so i bought a Raspberry Pi. I also bought a magazine to help me get a grasp of the basics. Now, I've downloaded Geany and I am using the Terminal tab of that for very simple commands. In the magazine, the first variable you come across should happen like this:

```
>>> a=2
>>> print(a*3)
6
```

However, when I write this, it actually ends up as the following:

```
>>> a=2
>>> print(a*3)
bash:syntax error near unexpected token 'a*3'
```

so, I tried it with spaces and it came back with the following:

```
>>> a=2
>>> print(a * 3)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'a'
```

I have also tried putting the same things into the LXTerminal of the Raspberry Pi (I am using the Raspbian OS). Please can someone point out where I am going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: `>>>` are for reference, you don't have to type those.

Comment: This is not really connected to Geany, as the terminal is really just a terminal embedded into Geany.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your errors are coming from bash, so you are not running the python interpreter.  Try entering `python` on a line on its own before entering your code fragments.

Comment: +1 because you explain how you get to understand where the problem is:   `bash: ...` means the interpreter is `bash`, not `python` so the python interpreter has not started yet. I believe also this information may help somebody who is starting using linux terminal/python langage

Answer (score 4):

You need to start python first and then enter the program statements *(note that $> and >>> are prompts from your system and  is the Enter key on your keyboard)*

```
$> python <ENTER>

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a=2 <ENTER>
>>> print(a*3) <ENTER>
```

The prompt after `python` above will be similar, but not identical as you're running linux/I'm running windows :)

Comment: and pay attention to not add the `>>>` at the beginning! they are just the python prompt